# Can't take value of a macro

Tags: clojure, leiningen

I have created a project using lein command.
This is my source file:

```
(ns database.core)
(defn movies[na rent qty]
  (spit "e.txt" (.toString [{:na na :rent rent :qty qty}]))
  (read-string (slurp "e.txt")))
```

This is my project file:

```
(ns database.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [database.core :refer :all]))

(deftest movies-test
  testing "movies"
  (let [jun (movies "Dark-knight" 12 6)]
    (is (= (get-in jun [0 :na]) "Dark-knight"))
    (is (= (get-in jun [0 :rent]) 12))
    (is (= (get-in jun [0 :qty]) 6))))
```

But when I try to run it i keep getting this error.
clojure.lang.Compiler$CompilerException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't take value of a macro: #'clojure.test/testing, compiling:(C:\Users\A\database\test\database\core_test.clj:5:1)

What could be the possible reasons for this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testing` macro must be enclosed in its own pair of parentheses so that it was invoked

```
(deftest movies-test
  (testing "movies"
    (let [jun (movies "Dark-knight" 12 6)]
      (is (= (get-in jun [0 :na]) "Dark-knight"))
      (is (= (get-in jun [0 :rent]) 12))
      (is (= (get-in jun [0 :qty]) 6)))))
```